# Function for the orbit of the International Space Station

Tags: functions, trigonometry, classical-mechanics

For a maths task in school, I am investigating the orbit of the International Space Station around the Earth. I understand that when the 3D movement in space is represented on a 2D  surface, the relationship is not sinusoidal, however I have created the following (simple) model, which I am unsure is the most accurate. Below you can also find my calculated values with the formula (in red), compared to the actual values from an online API. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

$y=51.64*\sin(x-304)$ 
(This only applies for one of the curves (the one pictured below), as the wave is translated 22.5 degrees to the right after each cycle.)

My data can be found in the following google doc:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ac8yQn8ybdtZWK8JyKAOIw46o3UJufAoidR5unjVeHs/edit?usp=sharing

[This is the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rUrG.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbital-mechanics

Comment: Do I understand correctly: You want to express the Latitude as a function of the Longitude? I don't think that is possible but you could probably parametrize the (Latitude, Longitude) pairs in a nice way that I don't know of

Comment: Thank you Maximilian, I will look into it!

Comment: You are new to Stack Exchange so you don't know that it's generally discouraged to cross-post the same question to multiple SE sites. ([question in Space SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43414/12102)) It might speed up getting an answer but it leads to *answer fragmentation* which is a problem for future readers. This is frequently confusing to new users, but we don't have a way to easily link answers to the same question that are posted on multiple sites.

Comment: I've [posted an answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43416/12102) in Space SE.